# nodejs: missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js

When I run nodejs http_test.js, which is attached following, it appeared "missing ) after argument list", I check the "(" and "{" but felt nothing wrong. help!

```
const http = require('http');
http.get({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 5000,
  path: '/123/',
  agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
}, (res) => {
  console.log(res)
  // Do stuff with response
})
```

Comment: Where are you running this?  Your environment may not support ES6 arrow functions.

Comment: node -v is v3.3.1 on MAC. You are  totally right! I change => into function() it works!

Answer (score 4):

Per @aaron-dufour's comment above, you are probably trying to run that code in an interpreter that does not support [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) 6.

If changing the contents of the file to the following works, then that's your problem:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 5000,
  path: '/123/',
  agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
}, function(res) {
  console.log(res)
  // Do stuff with response
});
```

In your case, you are using Nodejs, which *should* be okay, given [this article](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/). It may be that you are using a significantly out of date version. Try running `node -v` or `node --version` to see what version you're running.